# Getting the position of an HTML element in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have UIWebView loaded with an HTML file. I want to know the position (means x and y cordinates) of an HTML element on the screen when the webview is loaded.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by position? Is it on the screen, in the html or?

Comment: on the screen. The x and y cordinate from where its going to start on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to a combination of JavaScript and Objective-C to achieve this. You need a JavaScript function to pass back the screen position of certain element, and then translate that position to the screen on the iPhone.

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

One way is to write a JavaScript that takes an element ID and returns its position and the screen resolution. Then translate that to the webview resolution on iPhone screen. It gets trickier if the user is allowed to zoom and pan the webview though.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to write javaScript. Can we write a java script in which give my screen resolution as argument and then it can return me the element position?

Comment: With JQuery, you can get the size of the HTML document with $(document).height() and $(document).width(), as well as the position of a particular element: $('#element-id').position().